# Why was my account merged with a really old one?

Tags: support

I just told the blender stackexchange to send me notifications to a question at a certain email, and after that, my really old (1 year 2 months) account was merged with my 5-month-old account?

Why? I didn't tell anyone or click anything that merged my accounts. I don't want my accounts merged. The entire point of a new account was to have a fresh start from all the crap questions I asked as a total noob to this site.

The real bummer is that the bad questions from my really old account have tipped me below the threshhold for asking questions, even though my last 15 questions have 14 upvotes and only one downvote.

How can I un-merge the accounts? I didn't want them merged, I told nothing to merge it, and if necessary I will be creating another new account, both so that I can ask questions and also not have my profile's questions look like a 5-year-old asked them.

Edit: And now SO (or is it SE? I have never really got **exactly** what SE is) has linked this account with yet another account which I never used and has 1 rep. This merging nonsense is getting on my nerves...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So it caches the rep. Ok. Thanks for the info. I edited that bit out of my question.

Comment: Seems s.o. detected your _"old account"_, and merged it, as considering a sock puppet.

Comment: The notion of an "old" account is a strange one.  Where you a different person a year ago?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Meh. How can I get it undone?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes (See http://youtu.be/xn7ZaT3AgoU?t=9m29s). I do not want the posts of an immature, inexperienced and timid person to affect my current ability to write questions.

Comment: If this isn't regarding your Stack _Overflow_ account, it should be posted on [Meta.SE].

Comment: @JoshCaswell I only asked bad questions on StackOverflow, and I only got question-banned on StackOverflow, which is why I asked it here.

Comment: I don't think I understand what Blender.SE has to do with this, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're stating in comments:

> *"I am physically and mentally not the same person as that idiot a year ago who got himself question-banned with a string of dumb questions."*

That doesn't count when older accounts you have opened on SO, are detected to match the same IP (or email address). The system is detecting *'sock puppet'* accounts automatically and at least alert moderators about such observations.

Could be a mod decided your *old account* should be merged, since you didn't really change personality. You're still responsible for any questions or answers you gave, and that have been seen here.

---

While I'm well agreeing with our former german chancellor Adenauer: "Was geht mich mein Geschwätz von gestern an" ("What I should care about my babble from yesterday"), your account **won't be forgotten** by the SE system, and that claim of policy doesn't well apply here.

Sorry!

Comment: They don't actually have the same IP. I'm guessing SO linked them by me requesting one account to get notifications to the email of another account.

Comment: So, basically I should just make a new account?

Comment: @Joehot200 Somehow the system has detected that you're being the same person (for whatever criteria), and a mod decided to merge the accounts (that's what the situation you're describing looks like for me).

Comment: The merge was instant after confirming I wanted notifications to that email address, leading me to believe that it was automatic.

Comment: @Joehot200: Creating new accounts to get around question bans is a violation of guidelines here, and can end up getting your entire account suspended or even banned, and it can be broadened to an IP ban if you persist. Follow the guidelines to properly get your original account unbanned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - As a note, moderators can't merge accounts (that was removed from us a while ago). Only the system and employees can. The system did so automatically here.

Comment: @KenWhite I will attempt to do everything I can to get this account unbanned (e.g. making bounties on all my good unanswered questions which have been getting upvotes, answering certain questions if I can answer them, etc) before getting into methods that violate the guidelines.                           (Note that the word guideline is "a general rule, principle, or piece of advice." and not actually a set rule ("general rule" after a bit of googling means "usually" (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/as-a-general-rule) ).

Comment: @BradLarson Could you be so kind as to tell me how many upvotes I need to get out of my question ban, please?

Comment: @Joehot200 As far as I am aware, they can't, nor will they if they could.  That is a thing that would be prone to abuse.

Comment: @Joehot200: As used here ("site guidelines") it means the rules that you must follow in order to be allowed to participate here. That's "general use" of the term, and they are in fact "set rules", despite your efforts to say otherwise. The guidelines here say that creating new accounts to bypass punitive measures you've earned on the first account is not acceptable, and that doing so can (and usually does) result in that second account being automatically suspended as well. Continued creation of additional accounts to attempt to skirt the suspension can result in your being banned entirely.

Comment: @KenWhite OK, thanks for the info. Out of interest, how can I be "banned entirely"? If I use a VPN, a different email, and a totally unrelated username, how can anyone know if it is me or not? Also, I have been doing all I can to get out of the question-ban, but it's not looking too likely atm.

Comment: @Joehot200: The people at SE are extremely good at what they do. They've also been doing this for a long time now, and dealt with a lot of people trying to work around the guidelines here, as well as very clever bots and spammers and people trying to be disruptive.

Comment: @KenWhite I've managed to get out of the question-ban by bountying some of my questions as well as answering other peoples' questions, so no new account for me :).